# resize an img from echo php

Tags: php, css, image, echo

Can I pull an img tag from another website (using echo) and then style it through CSS to fit it into my own container div? My code is below - I'm just aiming to get the code to work and I will clean the code up later.

The major issue is I don't want to save the img into my files (it is dynamically changing from another source which I have parsed.) I was hoping I would be able to style a container div using max-height and width and just echo within that div but I haven't haven't had any luck changing the img size but I am able to adjust the margin within the container div and have the img respond so that is why I am here.

Would echoing the $compic->src work? If so what would that look like?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<title>Resize echo img</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
<body>
<div class="headimg">
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('url');

$compic = $html->find('img[title]', 0);

echo $compic 
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use `$compic->height` and `$compic->width` to resize the img

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you Yazan, but could you elaborate on that a little? I just tried to add the height and width using the sourceforge document as a guide but I keep getting syntax errors or "undefined variable".

Would I had them both to the same line as $compic so 0)->height('100')->width('100');?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wrap the img inside a parent element with a fixed with and height and the img element with width of 100% and a height of auto it should auto size

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="<?=$compic->src?>"> // not sure what the structure will be.
</div>
```

here is the css

```
.image-wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

using a structure like this lets you crop if the image is too tall, since sometimes aspect ratios don't match, you would do this by applying overflow hidden to .image-wrapper